Issue with Custom Keycloak REST API
We developed custom RESTful services as a Keycloak SPI following the official Keycloak example provided here. While the APIs are functioning as expected, we’re encountering an issue with the endpoint routing.
According to the example, the endpoint should be accessible via:
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/hello
However, it only works when we change the route to:
http://localhost:8080/realms/master/hello
The problem with this is that the /realms route does not include the /auth path, meaning these endpoints are not protected.
We are using Keycloak version 24.0.5. How can we ensure that our custom endpoints are protected while using the correct /auth route?
